# She has provided five witness statements

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Consider this sentence, please:

1. *She has provided five witness statements to the court in total, **detailing** acts of physical, mental violence etc.*

Can I write 1) as two separate sentences?

2. *She has provided five witness statements to the court in total. **These statements detail** acts of physical, mental violence etc.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She has provided five witness statements to the court in total. These
> statements detail acts of physical, mental violence etc.

Yes, that is grammatically correct and has the proper meaning.

Another possibility is:

*She has provided five witness statements to the court in total. These detail acts of physical, mental violence etc.*

The reason that the above version is unambiguous is that there is only one plural noun in the previous sentence and so "these" can only refer to "statements".

Comment: Would you call the participle clause in sentence (1) in the OP a **non-restrictive reduced relative clause**?